# OS X cannot install ember-cli at all

Tags: macos, ember-cli

after many tries , I am not far for giving up with ember testing ...

1/ I get npm ERR! registry error parsing son

2/ then I get nexpected end of input

```
node -v
v4.2.6
nam -v
2.14.12

npm install -g ember-cli
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Darwin 15.3.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ember-cli"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! nam  v2.14.12
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
... long JSON object ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it installed by running before :

```
 npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```

Then

```
$ npm install -g ember-cli@latest
```

installation ended correctly , beside the "standard" loads deprecated...

```
npm WARN deprecated lodash@2.4.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@2.4.1: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0
npm WARN deprecated lodash-node@3.10.2: This package has been discontinued in favor of lodash@^4.0.0
```

/Users/yves/.node/bin/ember -> /Users/yves/.node/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/bin/ember